# G/G/1 queue does not get empty

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, queueing-theory

> Consider an $G/G/1$ First In First Out (FIFO) queue in which $m$ people are waiting to be processed at time $t=0$. Then, people arrive according to i.i.d inter-arrival times with pdf $p(x)$ and rate $\lambda=(\int_{x=0}^{\infty} x p(x) dx)^{-1} $ and they are processed according to i.i.d processing times with pdf $q(x)$ and rate $\mu=(\int_{x=0}^{\infty} x q(x) dx)^{-1}$. Note that $\lambda=\mu$. What is the probability that from $t=0$ until the moment that the $n^{th}$ person leaves the queue, the queue never goes empty, as $n ,m \to \infty$, we know that $m<n$.

I can state this problem differently:

> A Gambler receives dollars according to a renewal process (\$1 per arrival) with inter-arrival time pdf $p(x)$ and spends single dollars according to another renewal process (\$1 per arrival) with inter-arrival time pdf $q(x)$. Assume the rate of earning $\lambda$ is equal to the rate of spending $\mu$. If he starts (at time $t=0$) with $m$ dollars, what is the probability that his money never reaches zero between time $t=0$ and the moment at which he spends $n^{th}$  dollar bill (we know that $m<n$)?

Is there anywhere I can find the answer? That should be a problem already discussed. Any useful keywords for search?

Comment: What is meant by "he rate of arrival is the same as the rate of the process"?  Does this mean $p(x)=q(x)$?

Comment: I just updated the problem statement to clarify this.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the answer to this is known? I am not an expert in queueing theory, but my impression has been that we can say practically nothing about $G/G/1$ queues.

Comment: @michael any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @mikespivey any idea?

Comment: @Did Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: @wece  Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: What does $\lambda = \mu i$ mean?  What is $i$?  Anyway the limiting answer likely depnds on the relative sizes of $m$ and $n$ as they both approach $\infty$. Also, this question seems related to the final PS comment on M/G/1 queues here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266200/expected-time-for-the-queue-to-become-empty

Comment: @Michael The $i$ was a typo which I removed it. All we know is that $m<n$. This is what exactly I want to know, what should be the size of $m$ relative to $n$ so that the probability that the queue does not get empty is equal to $0<p<1$. I read the PS there. That is talking about LIFO, however, my problem is about FIFO.

Comment: @MishaLavrov There is no reason to believe there is an answer. I was just asking to see if someone knows a solution in the literature.

Comment: @Did Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @Michael Do you mean writing a recursive relation?

Comment: No.  I don't know how to get an exact answer to your question, although bounds are possible. If the arrival process was Poisson with $\lambda < \mu$ then the expected time to empty can be computed exactly as a function of the initial number of jobs $m$. If $\lambda \geq \mu$ the expected time to empty is infinity and the infinite horizon fraction of time being empty is 0 with prob 1.