# Expected time for the queue to become empty.

Tags: conditional-expectation, queueing-theory, exponential-distribution, exponential-sum

**Question:**

Suppose, there is a queue ***A*** having ***i*** customers initially. The service time of the queue is Exponentially distributed with parameter ***$\mu$*** (i.e., mean service time of one customer in Queue **A** is 1/$\mu$). Arrival to queue A has Poisson distribution with mean **$\lambda$**. What is the expected time before queue A becomes empty for the first time?

**My approach:**

For the queue to be empty, service time of j customers should be less than the arrival time of $(j+1)^{th}$ customer (for j>=i).

=...

How do I proceed after this since the sums are Erlang distributed and I'm not able to tackle this.

Comment: What if you define $T_k$ as the expected time to empty, given you start with $k$ jobs, and $T_0=0$. Can you write a recursive relationship between $\{T_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$?  For example, can you write an expression for $T_1$ in terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$?

Comment: [Another classic and clever way to solve is to assume all departures are in Last-in-first-out (LIFO) order, and use insights from that (where each buffered packet is associated with a certain string of services until that packet leaves), but the above may be more direct.]

Comment: Let the random variable $C_{n}$ be the time till the system is empty again if there are now n customers present in the system. Clearly, $C_1$ is the length of a busy period, since a busy period starts when the first customer after an idle period arrives and it ends when the
system is empty again. The random variables $C_{n}$ satisfy the following recursion relation. Suppose there are n(> 0) customers in the system. Then the next event occurs after an
exponential time with parameter $\lambda$ + $\mu$. I used this to find a recursive relation and it worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for letting me know you solved it.  In the future you can use @[username] to direct comments to particular individuals.  If you want, you can answer your own question and mark it "best answer":  This is standard practice on stackexchange when you solve a problem based on suggestions in the comments.

Comment: PS:  Note that the LIFO scheduling idea is to notice that each of the initial $n$ packets generates its own busy period (one after the other).  Of course, this intuition usually comes _after_ solving the problem the direct way.  But this LIFO intuition is valuable since it lets you easily solve the problem even for M/G/1 queues, where the Markov chain approach would be more difficult.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael. I will try the second approach, too, and let you know if I could get the problem solved using it.

Comment: For others who didn’t solve it: this is clearly explained in section 4.6.2 of www.win.tue.nl/~iadan/queueing.pdf